# I am not able connect posgresql db due to SHA256 MD5

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

My connection string:
`"Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=MAXxKYC;User Id=postgres;Password=testpassword;"`

Exception:
`"Only AuthenticationClearTextPassword and AuthenticationMD5Password supported for now. Received: 10"`

how can I use "testpassword" as MD5 format in connection string

- I tried to use sha256 encrypted of the password **9f735e0df9a1ddc702bf0a1a7b83033f9f7153a00c29de82cedadc9957289b05**
- I tried to use MD5 encrypted of the password
  **e16b2ab8d12314bf4efbd6203906ea6c**
  but It didn't work

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to use MD5 instead of SHA256?

Comment: Yes I did but unfortunately still not working

Comment: I'm not familiar with Postgres but other posts for other programming languages suggested that it was solved by updating the client library to a newer version. Are you perhaps using an older version? Sorry if this isn't useful.

Comment: Thank you so much It solved my nuisance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a hashed password won't help: this is about the authentication method requested by the server. Your .NET provider is too old to know the requested `scram-sha-256` authentication method, which was introduced in PostgreSQL v10 four years ago.

Update to a more recent version of your .NET provider, and the problem will go away. If not, file a bug with the vendor of the .NET provider.